# Suspend Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, application-lifecycle

How to **suspend** a Windows Phone 8.1 **Silverlight** App when user presses the back key?

Answer (score 1):

A WP8.1 *Silverlight* has little [different lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx) than [WP8.1 *RunTime*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) - it inherits it from WP8.0 *Silverlight*.

Just in short - you don't have *Suspended/Resumed*, in WP8.0/8.1 *Silverlight*, instead your app can be put into *Dormant/Tombstoned* states. You app will call [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.activated(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Deactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated(v=vs.105).aspx) events.